# How to detect all javascripts are loaded in a page

Tags: javascript

I have a portal page which contains several portlets. Both my portlet and a couple of third-party portlets can have several javascript files or scripts tags.

My question is that how to detect if all javascripts have been completely loaded in the page.

Thank you in advance.

Note: I updated the question to make it clear:
My portlet is div within the portal page body tag; each third-party portlet is inside an iframe which has body tag.

What I want to do is that when all javascripts from all third-party portlets are loaded, my partlet will fire request.

Comment: AFAIK: It's not possible in the structure you're describing.

Comment: $(document).on('load',function(){})

Comment: @LIUFA It doesn't detect that all scripts are loaded.

Comment: @RahilWazir `$(document).ready` (jQuery) or `window.onload` (pure js) wouldn't help there?

Comment: @RahilWazir then trigger some event when they do finish loading, but there can not be any other generic answer to this question, as it depend on libraries themselves.

Comment: Sounds like you could do with looking at: http://labjs.com

Comment: Some scripts could be loaded through AJAX, there's no way to know about those. @WilliamGeorge I don't think the OP is going to control how the js gets loaded.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav The first one used to detect if DOM is loaded and latter used to detect if DOM and all media sources are loaded. But none of them can be used to detect if any script is loaded(downloaded) or not.

Comment: If some of the scripts are loaded by other people's code and loaded dynamically, either via dynamically inserted script tags or via ajax requests, then there is no way for you to know when all that activity is done.  Think about it.  A script could be dynamically loaded that when run could then load another script, etc...  If you aren't part of that loading process, you can't know when it's all done.

Comment: If any portlet is an iframe, those all have their own loading schedule too.  Basically, there is no generic answer to your question and your question doesn't contain enough specifics of exactly what you're trying to detect to offer any other kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

This only runs when document is loaded:

```
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
...
}
```

Comment: Only works for scripts in the original HTML of the page, not for dynamically loaded scripts.

Comment: `readyState` is whether the HTML has all been parsed. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#current-document-readiness

Answer (score 0):

Scripts that are loaded with the `<script>` tag are loaded synchronously, unless they have the defer attribute. That means they are loaded immediately after the `</script>` tag

The other way to load scripts is through `eval` and its family of JS generating functions (as when you request JS through AJAX). There's no way to detect that those executed, unless you know everything that needs to be loaded.

Short answer: It is not possible to know that all scripts have loaded, because a script that was loaded synchronously (from the HTML) may load another script asynchronously.

If you are adding all your JS through `<script>` tags, you can run code that depends on them immediately after the last closing `</script>` tag